# Graceful stop/terminate/shutdown of Kelp

Tags: kelp, cli

I am new to Kelp and trying out my first bot using OOB buysell configuration from CLI.

I have a very basic question...What is the way to shutdown/stop/terminate Kelp bot from CLI gracefully. If I do Cntl C, it kills the process and existing orders are not cancelled (needs to be done manually).

I found "terminate" command under the cmd folder in code, but it requires a configuration file and I couldn't find a sample for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an open issue for that [here](https://github.com/stellar/kelp/issues/572). If someone wants to jump in and tackle that issue I can review that PR and get it merged very quickly.

The "terminate" command is deprecated. The approach you are taking right now is the best approach for the CLI.

Since you are using the *buysell* trading template, you could try using the Kelp GUI which supports the *buysell* template. In the GUI, when you stop the bot it automatically attempts to remove outstanding offers. Once the bot is stopped, it shows you how many bids/asks are active for that bot. After successful termination it should show as 0 bid and 0 asks (or you can try restarting and stopping again as a way to "retry" the cancellation of offers).